# Which is faster – C or shell scripting – and why?

Tags: bash, shell-script, c

I was looking for a detailed info (if possible some statistics) about which is faster to run, C or a shell script. And also I would like to know the reasons for the answer.

P.S. This is not a question of which is better, I know when to use C and when to use shell scripting, but I just wanted to know more about their speed and performance comparisons.

Answer (score 9):

It depends. 
Browse this site (look for posts with negative scores)
and you'll see some examples of *horrible* shell scripts,
doing things like reading a file one line at a time
and then echoing each line into a program
that could have just handled the entire file. 
Naturally a script like that will run slowly.

But, if there is an existing program (or a small group of programs)
that do exactly what you want, without too much baggage,
then you can probably write a script very quickly
that will run faster than any C program you can write,
without a serious development effort. 
A lot of time and energy has been invested
in making some of the GNU/Linux programs very efficient. 
For example, under some conditions,
GNU `grep` doesn't need to look at every character of its input. 
Will the program *you* write be that clever?

Obligatory xkcd:

[image: Automation: In reality, ongoing development time outweighs the time saved by automating a task]

Answer (score 8):

Shell is interpreted, and by itself that means it cannot be as fast as an specially-coded application — provided that what ***executes*** is written by equally competent programmers.

More than that, the answer depends on how you count the time: you should count development time as well as the execution time of a script.